# Specs using AFMotion and WebStub

Tags: ios, rubymotion

I have a model I built around AFMotion.  When I tried to test the http headers with WebStub, the test deadlocked.  I tried to isolate the issue by taking my model out of the equation and writing a test using only WebStub and AFMotion.  The best I could come up with was this.

```
describe AFMotion::JSON do
  extend WebStub::SpecHelpers

  describe "#get" do

    it "includes headers" do
      stub = stub_request(:get, "http://localhost/test").
        to_return(json: {foo: 'bar'})

      stub.with_callback do |headers, _|
        headers.kind_of?(Hash).should == true
      end

      client = AFMotion::JSON.get("http://localhost/test") do
        resume
      end

      wait { }
    end
  end
end
```

This avoids the deadlock, but the stub callback does not get called

```
#get
  - includes headers [MISSING - empty specification: #get includes headers]

Bacon::Error: empty specification: #get includes headers
    spec.rb:437:in `block in finish_spec': #get - includes headers
    spec.rb:459:in `execute_block'
    spec.rb:437:in `finish_spec'
    spec.rb:427:in `run_postponed_block:'
    spec.rb:416:in `resume'
```

Is there some way I can test AFMotion headers without deadlocking?